# Full image size with parallax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I would like make same parallax banner like here http://gallery.smartadserver.com/mobile-parallax

What I have got is:
https://jsfiddle.net/mx5tfcwj/

```
var $wrap = $(".wrap");
var $parallax = $(".parallax-container");
function updatePosition() {
 var offsetFromWrap = $parallax.offset().top - $wrap.offset().top;

 $(".fixed").css({"top": offsetFromWrap * -1});
}

$wrap.scroll(function() {
 updatePosition();
});
```

The problem is you can not see end of the image when you scroll. Can you help me How should I calculate the position?

Comment: Increasing the `.wrapper` height to `700px`seems to make end of the image visible on scroll. https://jsbin.com/tifeli/edit?css,output

Comment: Nope, I can not use that. The height will be always variable. the wrap should simulate mobile screen device.